# View Source Code of Outlook Calendar Event

Tags: html, email, outlook, calendar, exchange-server

we want to examine the source code of the calendar event in Outlook (all version from Outlook 2010 till 2016) because of the integration between multi platforms (Google, Exchange, Exchange online).

Is there any way how to get a html source code of the calendar event? (Outlook - Calendar - open event/appointment - get a html source code?)

Note: Not the source code of the email (open mail -> right click -> view source code).

Thanks a lot for answers!

Comment: How do you mean?  Outlook doesn't use HTML (or the iCal) format for it's calendar events (or, indeed, any other data that it handles).  Instead it uses a rather obscure OLE format binary structure.  If you want to see exactly what is contained therein (on Windows) you'll need to use Outlook Spy.  On Mac I think you can use MailRaider.

Comment: Thanks, your info is what Ive needed.

Answer (score 2):

While in calendar, click "View" "Reading Pane" select some reading pane layout, and then you can right-click over the reading pane and select "View Source". If the event is not in html format, it will be greyed out.

Comment: Does not work in office version 1902. Any other email, I can right click and do "view source", but not for invites.

Comment: I meant the calendar event in the calendar view, not the invitation email.

Comment: You are right. It does work for some of the calendar events in the calendar view, but not all. That's the formatting thing you have mentioned in your answer. Thanks a lot.